# How to use LPology Simple Ajax Uploader cross-browser example on PHP/HTML page

Tags: php, ajax, cross-browser, progress-bar, uploader

I'm trying to install an uploader that has broad cross-browser compatibility (especially for older browsers), yet shows a progress bar whenever possible, and maybe the words "Uploading..." if not possible.

[LPology Simple Ajax Uploader](https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader) seems to have the features I want, and is supposed to be easy to install, yet I'm banging my head against the wall. As you can tell, I'm new to JavaScript.

Here's what I've done...

1. Uploaded the plugin to my server
2. Successfully installed APC extension to PHP and enabled rfc1867
3. Created a docs folder to hold uploads, with correct permissions
4. Put together UploadHandler.php file copied from https://www.lpology.com/code/ajaxuploader/phpdocs.php

   ```
   require_once("extras/Uploader.php");

   $uploader = new FileUpload('uploadFile');        
   $uploader->uploadDir  = '/docs/';
   $uploader->allowedExtensions = array('txt', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'rtf');
   $uploader->sizeLimit = 10485760;

   $result = $uploader->handleUpload('/docs/');
   if (!$result) {
   echo json_encode(array(
         'success' => false,
         'msg' => $uploader->getErrorMsg()
      ));    
   } else {
   echo json_encode(array(
           'success' => true,
           'file' => $uploader->getFileName()
        ));
   }
   ```
5. Tried the following code on my page (the script is based almost verbatim on LPology's Cross-Browser example)

   ```
   <input id="upload-btn" type="bHoutton" value="Choose file">
   <span style="padding-left:5px;vertical-align:middle;">
   <i>TXT, DOC, DOCX, PDF, and RTF (5000K max file size)</i>
   </span>

   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="ajax/Simple-Ajax-Uploader-master/SimpleAjaxUploader.min.js"></script>

   <script>
   var progress = document.getElementById('progress'), // progress bar
       loaderImg = document.getElementById('loaderImg'); // "loading" animated GIF
   errBox = document.getElementById('errormsg');

   var uploader = new ss.SimpleUpload({
           button: 'upload-btn',
           url: '../ajax/Simple-Ajax-Uploader-master/extras/uploadHandler.php', // server side handler
       progressUrl: '../ajax/Simple-Ajax-Uploader-master/extras/uploadProgress.php', // enables cross-browser progress support (more info below)
       responseType: 'json',
       name: 'uploadfile',
       maxSize: 5000,
       hoverClass: 'ui-state-hover',
       focusClass: 'ui-state-focus',
       disabledClass: 'ui-state-disabled',
       onExtError: function(filename, extension) {
           alert(filename + ' is not a permitted file type.' + "\n\n" + 'Only TXT, DOC, DOCX, PDF, and RTF files are allowed.');
       },
       onSizeError: function(filename, fileSize) {
           alert(filename + ' is too big. (5000K max file size)');
       },

       startXHR: function(filename, size) {
           progress.style.display = 'inline-block'; // show progress bar
           this.setProgressBar(progress); // designate as progress bar
           // Dynamically add a "Cancel" button to be displayed when upload begins
           // By doing it here ensures that it will only be added in browses which
           // support cancelling uploads
           var abort = document.createElement('button');
           wrap.appendChild(abort);
           abort.className = 'btn btn-sm btn-info';
           abort.innerHTML = 'Cancel';
           // Adds click event listener that will cancel the upload
           // The second argument is whether the button should be removed after the upload
           // true = yes, remove abort button after upload
           // false/default = do not remove
           this.setAbortBtn(abort, true);
       },
       endXHR: function(filename) {
           button.innerHTML = 'Uploading...';
           progress.style.display = 'none'; // hide progress bar
       },
       startNonXHR: function(filename) {
           loaderImg.style.display = 'inline-block'; // show animated GIF
       },
       endNonXHR: function(filename) {
           button.innerHTML = 'Uploading...';
           loaderImg.style.display = 'none'; // hide animated GIF
       }
   });
   </script>
   ```

When I click the "Choose File" button, no progress bar shows and nothing gets uploaded.  Firebug tells me that "progress" is null. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Is there anything your developer console that is indicating there's an error? Also, check the network tab of your web inspector, it will have the ajax request. click on it, and some decent information will be given. I'm going to go out on a limb and say that the issue is do to path locations.

Comment: I tried the simplest example given by the developer and still could not get anything to upload, nor could I get a progress bar to show. Currently, I can get it to display the name and size of the file to upload, but then an error message "Incorrect upload name or no file uploaded" appears. Nothing is uploaded anywhere. Looking at the network info, the file seems to be ending up as $_POST rather than $_FILES.  In the GitHub issues section, it's suggested to set multipart to true to fix this, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Amina, did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: I did get it mostly to work in that I could get it to show a progress bar and upload. If you can wait a week (I have a packed week ahead) I will post what worked. I don't remember what the bug was that held me up last time, but I'll try to compare the working code to the broken code.  I never published the answer because I got hung up on some other issues with the uploader (renaming the file; getting more than one uploader on a page to work) and so didn't consider it solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Have bootstrap to show the progress bar

```
<button id="mergedp" class="btn btn-large btn-primary"> upload </button>
<div id="progressOuter" class="progress progress-striped" style="display:none;"> 
<div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Or use the CSS in their demo for custom css